# Customer details based on booking count

Tags: oracle

Write a query to display user id and user name where the number of seats booked by the user in the individual booking is greater than 1. Display records in ascending order by user name.

I have tried this query and I m getting errors. Please help me!!

```
select u.user_id,u.name 
     from users u join bookingdetails bd 
     on u.name=bd.name
     join tickets t on u.user_id=t.user_id
     group by u.name
     having count(t.no_seats) > 1
     order by u.name;
```

Comment: update your question and add  your exact error message

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct u.user_id,u.name from users u 
join tickets t on u.user_id = t.user_id
where
u.user_id in( select user_id from tickets where no_seats>1)
order by u.name;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25188824)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your assignment it looks like you should do

```
WITH cteBookings AS (SELECT bd.USER_ID, SUM(t.NO_SEATS) AS TOTAL_SEATS_BOOKED
                       FROM BOOKINGDETAILS bd 
                       INNER JOIN PAYMENTS p
                         ON p.BD_ID = bd.BD_ID
                       INNER JOIN TICKETS t
                         ON t.TICKET_ID = p.TICKET_ID
                       GROUP BY bd.USER_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT b.USER_ID, u.USER_NAME
  FROM USERS u
  INNER JOIN cteBookings b
    ON b.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
  WHERE b.TOTAL_SEATS_BOOKED > 1
  ORDER BY u.USER_NAME ASC
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question, it asks for the individual bookings > 1
So, the solution is very simple i.e, for ***each ticket_id***, the ***no of seats should be greater than 1***.

SELECT DISTINCT(user_id),name

FROM Tickets inner join Users
USING (user_id)

WHERE no_seats>1

ORDER BY name;

Answer (score 0):

It will simpler if you try it without joins.

A simple example using a subquery:

```
select  user_id, name from users 
where user_id = any(select distinct user_id from tickets where no_seats > 1) 
order by name asc;
```